# Are there any builtin IMultiValueConverts in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, imultivalueconverter

I'm writing a MultiBinding containing two bindings - each returning a bool. Using MultiBindings you need to specify an IMultiValueConverter. In my case this converter should take two bools and return the AND of them. This is really simple to write, but do I have to? This feels like the most basic MultiValueConverter, and I don't want to write one if there is already an existing one in .NET.

So - is there? And if so - which built in IMultiValueConverters are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing comes into my mind that will suit you directly. Reflector says there are only three open IMultiValueConverters there:

- [BorderGapMaskConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.bordergapmaskconverter.aspx)
- [MenuScrollingVisibilityConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuscrollingvisibilityconverter.aspx)
- [JournalEntryUnifiedViewConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.journalentryunifiedviewconverter.aspx)

This answer is useless. But maybe you'll find something helpful among Kent Boogaart's [WPF converters](http://wpfconverters.codeplex.com/) library.

Cheers, Anvaka.

Comment: Thx Anvaka! For this specific simple converter I'll create it myself in no time. Just didn't want to if there already is one - like there are some built in IValueConverters. So no need to use a library, but nice to know anyway!